# Working with dictionary of dataframes and applying functions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm starting to learn working with dictionaries of dataframes.
I can import an excel file, and select the sheets I want to work with as follows:

```
all_sheets = pd.ExcelFile(file.xlsx").sheet_names
all_sheets
['HB-01', 'NX2-452', 'Notes']

prefixes = ('Notes', 'Summary')
sheets_for_analysis = [x for x in all_sheets if not x.startswith(prefixes)]
sheets_for_analysis
['HB-01', 'NX2-452']

data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\iancr\Desktop\dfs in dict.xlsx", sheet_name = sheets_for_analysis)
data
{'HB-01':    Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1    Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4    Unnamed: 5  \
 0         NaN  Product ID  Product Name      Notes     Counts  Worksheet No   
 1         NaN        1000          Comb        NaN         25       367-389   
 2         NaN        1000          Comb        NaN         25       367-389   
 3         NaN        1000          Comb        NaN         25       372-112   
 4         NaN        3000         Brush  Squashed          25           763   
 5         NaN        3000         Brush        NaN         25           786   
 6         NaN        3000         Brush        NaN         25           381   
 
   Unnamed: 6  
 0     Andrew  
 1         90  
 2         86  
 3         79  
 4       < 36  
 5       < 23  
 6       < 21  ,
 'NX2-452':    Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1    Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5  \
 0         NaN  Product ID  Product Name   Sequence      Notes     Counts   
 1         NaN        1000          Comb          1        NaN         25   
 2         NaN        1000          Comb          2        NaN         25   
 3         NaN        1000          Comb          3        NaN         25   
 4         NaN        3000         Brush         12        NaN         25   
 5         NaN        3000         Brush         12        NaN         25   
 6         NaN        3000         Brush         13        NaN         25   
 7         NaN        9000           Air         14        NaN         25   
 8         NaN        9000           Air         15    Too hot         25   
 9         NaN        9000           Air         16        NaN         25   
 
      Unnamed: 6 Unnamed: 7 Unnamed: 8 Unnamed: 9 Unnamed: 10  
 0  Worksheet No      Susan       Neil       Paul       Cindy  
 1          8798       < 22         42         56          76  
 2          8798         32       < 32         43          56  
 3          8798         45         12         24          79  
 4           763         12         43       < 56          67  
 5           786         21         63         77          54  
 6           381         16         45         65          55  
 7           354       > 44         36         46          98  
 8           354         53         31         44          94  
 9           386         46         33         41          90  }
```

I want to have index 0 as the column headers and drop that row on all dataframes, so:

```
for key, df in data.items():
    df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0], inplace =True)
    df.drop(index=df.index[0], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

And this gives the desired result.

But, then I want to apply two functions to each dataframe, one is applied to where the 'Product ID' is Comb, and the other to everything else. The two functions are below, and they essentially clean up the data in the dataframe and return certain values:

```
def stripdata_comb(data):
    if str(data).startswith("<"):
        return '0'
    
    elif str(data).startswith(">"):
        return str(data).split(' ')[1]
    
    else:
        return data

def stripdata_no_comb(data):
    if str(data).startswith("<"):
        return str(data).split (' ')[1]
    
    elif str(data).startswith(">"):
        return str(data).split(' ')[1]
```

If I was working with a single dataframe, I'd filter on the 'Product ID' and apply the functions:

```
comb = df[df['Product ID'] == 'Comb']
not_comb = df[df['Product ID'] != 'Comb'] 

for col in comb.columns:
       comb[col] = comb[col].apply(stripdata_comb)
for col in not_comb.columns: 
       not_comb[col] = not_comb[col].apply(stripdata_no_comb)
```

So if I want to apply these functions to my dictionary of dataframes, I'm attempting the following:

```
for key, df in data.items(): 
    comb = df[df['Product ID']=='Comb'].apply(stripdata_comb)
    not_comb = df[df['Product ID'] != 'Comb'].apply(stripdata_no_comb)
```

I don't get any errors, but the dataframes in the dictionary are unchanged. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "Where am I going wrong?" in your last piece of code, nowhere do you mutate the dataframe objects, which you are relying on

Answer (score 0):

In your last code example, you are iterating over `data`. But the only variables you are updating are `comb` and `not_comb`. So not the dictionary with all of your dataframes.

I think what you want is:

```py
for key, df in data.items(): 
   data[key][df['Product ID'] == 'Comb'] = df[df['Product ID'] == 'Comb'].apply(stripdata_comb)
   data[key][df['Product ID'] != 'Comb'] = df[df['Product ID'] != 'Comb'].apply(stripdata_no_comb)
```

`data[key][df['Product ID'] == 'Comb']` using this overrides only the columns where `df['Product ID'] == 'Comb'` in the original dataframe inside of data.

Comment: I've tried your solution @Marius, but it's not returning the amended dataframes in the dict